# Extracting part of a string in R

Tags: r

I am using `sub()` to get parts of a string, and looking for something a bit specific:

If I have `string` below, and want the 1st character after the pattern `"OOP"`. How would the be done using `sub()` Also, where can I find the metacharacters in R and their uses (i.e "//" and ".*")

```
string <- "MKHJK__090978_166g7_nsuOOPTJ_Complete"
# would like to output: "T"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the first character after `'OOP'` using `sub` you can do -

```
string <- "MKHJK__090978_166g7_nsuOOPTJ_Complete"
sub('.*OOP(.).*', '\\1', string)
#[1] "T"
```

Comment: Thanks for this - Do you have a resource to lookup the metacharacters: i.e. "(.)" and ".*"

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good resource to learn about regular expression in general. If you want something R-specific you can start with `?regex`.

Answer (score 1):

Check `stringr`. E.g.:

```r
string <- "MKHJK__090978_166g7_nsuOOPTJ_Complete"
x <- stringr::str_extract(string, "OOP.?")
stringr::str_sub(x, start= -1)

> T
```

See https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
regmatches(string, regexpr("(?<=OOP)(.)", string, perl = TRUE))
[1] "T"
```

#### data

```
string <- "MKHJK__090978_166g7_nsuOOPTJ_Complete"
```